# How to apply validation to cloned elements in Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

There is a textbox with label; having validation of isnumeric.

```
Money: <input type="text" id="dollar" name="dollar" data-require-numeric="true" value=""> 
//Textbox with id dollar0
```

At run time, I have created clone of above; by clicking on button named add; and this created another textbox with different id and other attributes same; say.

```
Money: <input type="text" id="dollar1" name="dollar1" data-require-numeric="true" value="">
//Cloned textbox; cloned by clicking on a button named clone
```

On both textboxes data-require-numeric is true.

**Issue**: For default textbox the JQuery validation is getting executed. But for new clone; JQuery is not running.

Following is jquery:

```
var economy= { 
init: function () {
$('input[type="text"][data-require-numeric]').on("change keyup paste", function () {
        check isnumeric; if yes then border red
    });
}};
$(economy.init);
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : You need to register click event handler using `.on()` in following way where registering the click handler for `document` which will delegate the event to `'input[type="text"][data-require-numeric]'`. This way you can handle events for dynamically added elements.

```
var economy= { 
init: function () {
$(document).on("change keyup paste",'input[type="text"][data-require-numeric]', 
    function () {
        check isnumeric; if yes then border red
    });
}};
$(economy.init);
```

Comment: Wao. It seems to me working. Let me test thoroughly before marking it an answer :)

Comment: can you pls explain about "change keyup paste" this.

Comment: @fatherazrael, happy to help you

Comment: @raghavendra, OP is doing validation on change, keyup or paste event.

Comment: @Bhushan "paste" is a new event in jquery or it is old bcoz never seen that event..

Comment: @Light, it was there since 2011 that I know but I could not find any API documentation on it.

Answer (score 0):

to bind change event on dynamic dom elements . use class reference instead of id . And bind the event to its parent like,

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

$(".parent").on("keyup",".dynamicdom",function(e){
value = $(e.target).val()

//then do your validation here. and you can attach multiple events to it
})

})
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <input type="text" class="dynamicdom" >
  <input type="text" class="dynamicdom" >
 </div>
```